# Different sqlite databases for testing and actual use in android app

Tags: android, sqlite, testing, greendao, greenrobot-eventbus

Disclaimer - I have used GreenDAO ORM for creating and managing the sqlite db from within my android app.

For my android app, while writing unit tests, I wish to tell the app to switch to using a certain db which is different from the normal one in order to make sure that the tests do not contaminate the real db. Correspondingly I have used appropriate functions to create new db and switch to it like this

```
public class DbTests extends ApplicationTestCase<MyApp> {
private static final String TAG = "DbTests";
private MyApp mApplication;
private Context mContext;

public DbTests() {
    super(MyApp.class);
}

@Override
protected void setUp() throws Exception {
    Log.d(TAG, "in setUp");
    super.setUp();
    createApplication();
    mApplication = getApplication();
    Log.d(TAG, "setUp done");
}

@Override
public void tearDown() throws Exception {
    super.tearDown();
}


private void setUpFreshInstallNoDataCase(boolean val) {
    assertNotNull(mApplication);
    LocalDataHelpers.setupLocalData(mApplication, InitialConditions.FreshInstallNoData);
    try {
        Thread.sleep(1000);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public void testFreshInstallNoDataCase() {
    Log.d(TAG, "testFreshInstallNoDataCase");
    setUpFreshInstallNoDataCase(true);

    mContext = mApplication.getApplicationContext();
    assertEquals(0, PersonRepository.getAllPersons(mContext).size());
}
}



public class LocalDataHelpers {
public static final String TAG = "LocalDataHelpers";

static MyApp globalApplication;

public static void setupLocalData(MyApp app, String condition) {
    globalApplication = app;
    if(globalApplication.daoSession != null){
        Log.d(TAG, "daoSession not null");
        globalApplication.daoSession.clear();
        globalApplication.setupDatabase(condition);     
    }
}
}
```

In my application onCreate and setupDatabase are like this

```
public void onCreate() {
    Log.d(TAG, "onCreate");
    super.onCreate();
    EventBus.getDefault().register(this);
    EventBus.getDefault().post(new PersonEvents.FetchPersonsFromServer());
    setupDatabase(InitialConditions.DefaultSetUp);
}

private void setupDatabase(String condition) {
    DaoMaster.DevOpenHelper helper = null;
    SQLiteDatabase db = null;
    DaoMaster daoMaster = null;
    if (condition.equals(InitialConditions.DefaultSetUp)) {
        helper = new DaoMaster.DevOpenHelper(this, "example-db", null);
        db = helper.getWritableDatabase();
        daoMaster = new DaoMaster(db);
    }
    else if (condition.equals(InitialConditions.FreshInstallNoData)) {
        helper = new DaoMaster.DevOpenHelper(this, "freshInstallNoData-db", null);
        db = helper.getWritableDatabase();
        daoMaster = new DaoMaster(db);
        //clear all possible data here by dropping all tables and recreate
        Log.d(TAG, "Dropping all tables and recreating them");
        DaoMaster.dropAllTables(db, true);
        DaoMaster.createAllTables(db, false);
    }
    if (helper != null && db != null && daoMaster != null) {
        daoSession.clear();
        daoSession = daoMaster.newSession();
    }
    else {
        Log.e(TAG, "setupDatabase Error : condition " + condition + ", either helper or db or daomaster is null");
    }
    List<Pair<String, String>> dbs = getDaoSession().getDatabase().getAttachedDbs();
    for (Pair<String, String> pair : dbs) {
        Log.d(TAG, "setupDatabase <" + pair.first + ", " + pair.second + ">");
    }
}
```

The onEvent for FetchPersonsFromServer gets a list of persons and saves them to the db using PersonDao.

Now If I clear all app data from my device and run the test directly, as expected the test passes. However if I run the app normally, and then run tests, the assert statement fails at

```
assertEquals(0, PersonRepository.getAllPersons(mContext).size());
```

with the size as that of the default db value.

I am going crazy trying to figure out why. The log statements in setupDatabase show that the correct db name is showing up ie freshdbinstall-db...

Are two dbs not allowed in android? Logically there should be no issues? Is it GreenDao which doesn't allow it? Am I making some basic mistakes...

Please help.

---

Edit : Is [Creating more than 1 *.db file with greenDao android ORM library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23196543/creating-more-than-1-db-file-with-greendao-android-orm-library) even vaguely relevant?

### UPDATE 1

I have used adb shell, run-as  cat  /sdcard/debug/db and adb pull to look at both the default and fresh databases after the test failure

The fresh database is as expected with no Person entries and 10 entries in default. So I guess the problem lies in the assert/query call... It seems to be using the default db for some reason... Looking at repository code which is

```
public static List<Person> getAllPersons(Context context) {
    return getPersonDao(context).loadAll();
}

private static PersonDao getPersonDao(Context c) {
    return ((MyApp) c.getApplicationContext()).getDaoSession().getPersonDao();
}
```

As per this seems like session is not being updated and the previous one is still being used

Answer (score 0):

If [Robolectric](http://robolectric.org/) is an option for you, this is how we use an in-memory SQLite database with populated test data:

**TestApplication.java**

```
public class TestApplication extends YourApplication
    implements TestLifecycleApplication {

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        YourProvider provider = new YourProvider(YOUR_CONTENT_AUTHORITY);
        provider.onCreate();
        ShadowContentResolver.registerProvider(YOUR_CONTENT_AUTHORITY, provider);
    }
    ...
}
```

**SomeTest.java**

```
@RunWith(RobolectricTestRunner.class)
public class SomeTest {
    @Test
    public void testSQLite() {
        // insert test data into in-memory SQLite
        ShadowContentResolver resolver = shadowOf(Robolectric.getShadowApplication().getContentResolver());
        ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
        cv.put("column_name", "column_value");
        resolver.insert(YOUR_CONTENT_URI, cv);
        // test against in-memory SQLite
        ...
    }
    ...
}
```

Sorry I forget the source of article where I read this.